# PHP dynamic image creation not working

Tags: php, regex, gd

With the following script, I split text into sentences, and create images dynamically from each sentence.  My for loop is not executing properly. I do not understand, why? The image creation function is being called only once, creating just one image, despite the text contains 4 distinct sentences. The purpose of the script is creating four images and saving them into the hard drive. I need your suggestions.

```
<?php
    $text = "Hello PHP! some sentences. very difficult, yes? that's for sure!?!";

    $chunks = preg_split('#[\r\n]#', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    foreach($chunks as $val)
    {
        preg_match_all('#(?:\s[a-z]\.(?:[a-z]\.)?|.)+?[.?!]+#i', $val, $paragraph);
            foreach($paragraph[0] as $val)
            {
                $sentences[] = ltrim($val);
            }
    }

    $sentencesCount = count($sentences);

        for ($i=0; $i <$sentencesCount ; $i++) 
        { 
                //$value = $sentences[$i];
                //echo $value . "<br />";

            $image = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 50);
            imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, 199, 49, 0xFFFFFF); //white


            $fontfile = 'verdana.ttf';

            imagefttext($image, 20, 0, 20, 35, 0x000000, $fontfile, $sentences[$i]);

            header('Content-type: image/png');
            imagepng($image);   
            //Save the image after the current timestamp.
            imagepng($image, "savedimages/" . time() . ".png");
            //Clean up.
            imagedestroy($image); 

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 5):

All the images are getting the same filename because the code runs fast enough such that the [`time()`](http://php.net/time) function (which returns the time in seconds) is giving you the same value 4 times. So you're overwriting the same file 4 times in this line:

```
imagepng($image, "savedimages/" . time() . ".png");
```

As a workaround, you can append a random number for uniqueness using the [`rand()`](http://php.net/rand) function.

```
imagepng($image, "savedimages/" . time() . "-" . rand() . ".png");
```

Better yet, use php's built-in [`tempnam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) function to generate a unique filename.

Comment: Dear Asaph, very good answer. Do you own a site? Have a contact email?

Comment: @user2665522 Please mark this answer as correct if it has resolved your problem. Thanks.